# Java - How to split after // , between /* and */ , between " and " , between ' and ' all together?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split it as a text using java. I want to cut all the comments and everything between " "  and ' '.

I removed comments with // using this:

```
"(//.*)"
```

Now I want to get rid of others. Is there a way to make it all together ? Or do I have to split it 4 times ?

By the way, I'm using `Pattern.DOTALL` mode now. So `\\.` will select everything including new lines. But I don't have to use that mode.

Comment: Include a sample input with expected output as well.

Comment: Note that removing Java or C++ comments properly is extremely difficult, and requires full lexical parser. What if source code has this line: `s = "//";`?

Comment: It's okay. Because I want to remove everything between " " too.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

```
    ArrayList<String> rows= new ArrayList<>();


    try (Scanner cfile = new Scanner(new File("codefile"))) {


      while (cfile.hasNextLine()) {
        rows.add(cfile.nextLine());
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    for(String row: rows) {
if(row.contains("/*")) ...
    }
```

Comment: It's a C code. There will be something like `x = a/b;` So you can't just put "/"

Comment: If you read code by rows and read first char at row. If it is comment row you just remove that row. You can also use .contains() for row.

Comment: @ville Comments do not have to be the first thing in a line.

Comment: You can use  p.indexOf("/*") and substring()

Answer (score 0):

I solved it : `(\\/\\/.*)|(\\/\\*[^\\*\\/]*\\*\\/)|(\".*\")|('.*')`